# Import imdb data into wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, imdb

I want to import imdb data into my wordpress website to be displayed along side the embeded videos. Can you suggest some good plugin for this purpose? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Brainy Kid

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefear import the data into a MySQL table and then write my own code using PHP and starting from a white WP page.

If you are looking for a more standard solution I suggest you to try the [IMDB Connector](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/imdb-connector/) plug-in for Wordpress.